# Canonical form of symmetric integer matrix M

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Let $M$, $N$ be a symmetric matrix over a ring $R$.
$M$ and $N$ are said to be equivalent if there exist an invertible
matrix $U$ (over the same ring $R$) such that $N=U M U^T$ ($U^T$ is the transpose of $U$).
A question is that what is the simple canonical form of $M$
under such an equivalent relation.

We know that when $R$ is the ring of real numbers, every
real symmetric matrix is equivalent to
an diagonal matrix with diagonal entries being 1, -1, or 0.

When $R$ is the ring of integers, do we have a similar result?

If there is no nice results, we may assume $M$
to satisfy additional conditions:

(a) $|\det(M)|=1$

(b) There exist a $J$ such that $J^2=1$ and $JMJ^T=-M$.

Thanks!

Edit:  I am also interested in finding the simple canonical form of integer symmetric matrices $M$, that satisfy

(a) $|\det(M)|=1$

(b) There exist a $J$ such that $J^2=-1$ and $JMJ^T=-M$.

Comment: There is not really any canonical form, even for definite matrices, as soon as dimension reaches 4. Could you please indicate some examples in dimension 2 and dimension 4? Your condition (b) requires that $\det M = \det (-M),$ so the dimension is even. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all in the correct reference. Cassels, *Rational Quadratic Forms*, chapter 9 "Integral Forms over the Rational Integers," pages 163-164, Examples 9-11. Example 11(i) says that, for "odd" matrices, we can cut down the dimension by 2 and write $y_1^2 - y_2^2 + g(z_1, \ldots , z_{n-2}).$ The determinant of $g$ is still $\pm 1,$ so the only problem is that $g$ may be "even."

Next, if $f$ is "even" the quadratic form can, in fact, be written  $ 2y_1 y_2 + g(z_1, \ldots , z_{n-2}).$

So, all we really need is to show, as in Sylvester's Law of Inertia, that the resulting form $g$ continues to be indefinite. Presumably your condition with $J M J^T = -M$ can do this.

Otherwise, without your $J$ condition, Example 11(vi) says that either $f$ or $-f,$ if "even," is equivalent to a sum of some $2x_j y_j$ terms along with a single $\mathbb E_8$ lattice. [CASSELS](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html)

I was uneasy about the possible need to mix 2 by 2 blocks of both types, despite Hahn's statement, but 
$$  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\\
 2 & 3  & 1 & 2 \\\
 0 & 1 & 1  & 1  \\\ 
 2 & 3 & 2  & 1  
\end{array} 
  \right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & -1  & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & 0 & 0  & 1  \\\ 
 0 & 0 & 1  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\\
 4 & 3  & 1 & 3 \\\
 2 & 1 & 1  & 2  \\\ 
 2 & 2 & 1  & 1  
\end{array} 
  \right) = 
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & -1  & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & 0 & 1  & 0  \\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0  & -1  
\end{array} 
  \right)
 $$

Comment: Indeed, one needs the right refs (and right term to Google). On page 672 of http://math.nd.edu/assets/20630/hahntoulouse.pdf: An odd indefinite unimodular quadratic form over Z is equivalent to $M=a_1x_1^2+...+a_nx_n^2$ with $a_i=\pm 1$. 
An even indefinite unimodular quadratic form is equivalent to $M=2x_1x_2+2x_3x_4+...+E_8+E_8+...$
or $M=2x_1x_2+2x_3x_4+...-E_8-E_8-...$
where $E_8$ is the quadratic form of E8 lattice of the remaining variables. 


Comment: With the additional condition $JMJ^T=−M$, we see that the canonical form for even $M$ is the direct sum of $2x_1x_2$, and the canonical form for odd $M$ is the direct sum of $x_1^2−x_2^2$.

Comment: @Xiao-Gang Wen, I think we need to allow for some of both types of 2 by 2 blocks. Given letters $w,x,y,z,$ I think the form $$ w^2 - x^2 + 2 y z   $$ is not necessarily equivalent to any $$ r^2 - s^2 + t^2 - u^2  $$ in letters $r,s,t,u.$ This is what I was worried about when I wrote, above, "so the only problem is that $g$ may be even." Anyway, it should not take long to check this one example, now that I know what I am looking at. 

Comment: @Xiao-Gang Wen, On the other hand, the Hahn survey is very nice and the theorem you quote entirely clear. Strange that I do not recognize his name, I guess he does the more algebraic side of this area. The references in his article are just about everything I would recommend for integral forms, outside of Watson and SPLAG.

Answer (score 3):

For symplectic unimodular symmetric (or skew) matrices, such a result is [shown in](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/zarrow.pdf)
Zarrow, Robert
A canonical form for symmetric and skew-symmetric extended symplectic modular matrices with applications to Riemann surface theory.
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 204 (1975), 207–227.

You might be able to extend it to the nonsymplectic case (though I am a bit skeptical).

Comment: Indeed, Zarrow came very close to what I need.
Zarrow found a simple canonical form the symmetric
that satisfy (a) and 

(b') There exist a $J$ such that $J^2=-1$ and $J M J^T=−M^{-1}$.



Comment: I am also interested finding the canonical form for symmetric matrices
that satisfy (a) and (b'') There exist a $J$ such that $J^2=−1$ and $J M J^T=−M$.

Comment: it is customary to up-vote answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to diagonalize the quadratic form $2xy.$ As far as your conditions, we have
$$ M = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 1  \\\
   1  & 0  
\end{array} 
\right) $$ and
$$ J = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0  \\\
   0  & -1  
\end{array} 
\right), $$ with
$$  \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0  \\\
   0  & -1  
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 1  \\\
   1  & 0  
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0  \\\
   0  & -1  
\end{array} 
\right) = 
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -1  \\\
   -1  & 0  
\end{array} 
\right)
 $$ 
However, the only diagonal matrices with determinant $-1$ are $\pm J,$ which does not work as $x^2 - y^2$ does not represent any numbers congruent to $2 \pmod 4.$

Let's see, Conway and Sloane refer to Watson for his 2-adic canonical form for their work on the Mass Formula, so I can recommend the book Integral Quadratic Forms by George Leo Watson. More recent, SPLAG, which is Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups by Conway and Sloane.

Comment: I suppose it is possible that one of your matrices must be equivalent to something that decomposes into 2 by 2 blocks, along the main diagonal only. That is the sort of thing that L. E. Dickson liked, but I do not believe he considered your condition. If so, you are probably in good shape.  So I guess the questions are (A) have you proved your 2 by 2 case (you say "may have," and (B) does it appear that 4 by 4 examples decompose into blocks?

Comment: We do not need to diagonalize M. We just need to find some simple canonical form. We may have the following results for 2 x 2 integer matrices that satisfy (a) and (b): All even matrices are equivalent to
$$
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 1  \\
   1  & 0 
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

All odd matrices are equivalent to
$$
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 1  \\
   1  & 1 
\end{array} 
\right) \sim
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0  \\
   0  & -1 
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

Do we have a similar simple result in general? – Xiao-Gang Wen 0 secs ago – Xiao-Gang Wen 0 secs ago

Comment: I'm reading Watson, I do not see an answer yet. It would be nice to see some 4 by 4 examples.  

Comment: What are even and odd matrices?

Comment: @Igor, I think it is whether the quadratic form takes only even values or sometimes odd. So this is consistent with SPLAG terminology for lattices.